# Schedule in HaxeFlixel

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

What is the best way to have a schedule of events in HaxeFlixel?  In other words, I would like to have a function `onTime(time:Int, function:Data->Void, data:Data):Void` which causes `function(data)` to be executed at time `time`.  I would then make a `.json` file with a whole list of timestamped functions and data and iterate through it so that each function is called with the specified data at the specified time.

Comment: One way would be to create FlxTimers (http://flixel.org/docs/org/flixel/FlxTimer.html) for each event, passing the timers the required time and callback functions that you bind the data to (https://haxe.org/manual/lf-function-bindings.html)